# Spring Boot Bootstrap Modal Login from home

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have login working from the actual login "/login" page, and on the home page "/" i have a modal window, when i get an error, it redirects to the login page and displays the error messages no problem. when the login is correct, it logs the user in but after a refresh you're logged out again. Not sure how to do the whole modal thing. Do I need a method and assign the form maybe a modelAttribute to both? I tried that but didn't work.

Here is my modal login form in home "/"

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title">Please sign in</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <c:if test="${param.error != null }">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid username and password
                    </div>
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="${param.logout != null }">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">You're signed out</div>
                </c:if>

                <form:form role="form" action="/login" commandName="login"
                    method="post" id="myForm">
                    <label for="username">Email address: </label>
                    <input id="username" name="username" type="email"
                        class="form-control" />

                    <p class="help-block">Enter your email</p>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password"
                            id="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
                        <form:errors cssClass="error" path="password" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label> <!--  input the spring expects --> <input
                            name="_spring_security_remember_me" type="checkbox">remember
                            me
                        </label>
                    </div>


                    <button type="submit" id="signupButton" name="signupButton"
                        class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>

                </form:form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

command name is just a placeholder, how would I integrate modelAttribute to allow login from the home page as well?

in my config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/home", "/error", "/signup", "/forgot-password", "/reset-password", "/public/**", "/users/*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginPage("/").loginPage("/home").permitAll().and().rememberMe().key(rememberMeKey).rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices()).and().logout().permitAll();


}
```

in the last line in config method, am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: What do you mean by "user is logged out after refresh". I don't think user gets logged out of the Spring Security context. First I would assume that you have a problem with your UI as you would have to hide/show fragments of your page depending if user is authenticated or not.

Comment: when I login from /login, i can edit my user profile. when i log in from the modal window, session expired as soon as i click a link or refresh the page, pretty clear actually